# How to pass variables to Puppeteer page.on?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-devtools, chromium, puppeteer

If I have this

`page.on('response', this.extractImages);`

**First question:** How do I pass additional variables into `this.extractImages` function? The function is defined as `extractImages(...args)` but `args` is only this:

```
[ Response {
    _client:
     Session {
       domain: null,
       _events: [Object],
       _eventsCount: 15,
       _maxListeners: undefined,
       _lastId: 9,
       _callbacks: Map {},
       _connection: [Object],
       _targetId: '3879dfee-f3de-48a8-a735-ac3b8cb4110e',
       _sessionId: '3879dfee-f3de-48a8-a735-ac3b8cb4110e:1' },
    _request:
     Request {
       _client: [Object],
       _requestId: '39213.259',
       _interceptionId: null,
       _interceptionHandled: false,
       _response: [Circular],
       _completePromiseFulfill: [Function],
       _completePromise: [Object],
       url: 'https://cm.g.doubleclick.net/pixel?google_nid=rubicon&google_cm&google_sc&google_awbid',
       method: 'GET',
       postData: undefined,
       headers: [Object] },
    _contentPromise: null,
    headers:
     Map {
       'pragma' => 'no-cache',
       'date' => 'Sat, 09 Sep 2017 06:46:10 GMT',
       'server' => 'HTTP server (unknown)',
       'status' => '302',
       'p3p' => 'policyref="https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/gcn_p3p_.xml", CP="CURa ADMa DEVa TAIo PSAo PSDo OUR IND UNI PUR INT DEM STA PRE COM NAV OTC NOI DSP COR"',
       'location' => 'https://pixel.rubiconproject.com/tap.php?v=7751&nid=2249&expires=30&put=CAESEBK_unCwxxtI7mj-7CUjh3g&google_cver=1',
       'cache-control' => 'no-cache, must-revalidate',
       'content-type' => 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
       'alt-svc' => 'quic="googleads.g.doubleclick.net:443"; ma=2592000; v="39,38,37,35",quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="39,38,37,35"',
       'content-length' => '326',
       'x-xss-protection' => '1; mode=block',
       'expires' => 'Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT' },
    status: 302,
    ok: false,
    url: 'https://cm.g.doubleclick.net/pixel?google_nid=rubicon&google_cm&google_sc&google_awbid' } ]
```

**Second question:** How do I get the return from the function that `page.on` triggered (in this case: `this.extractImages`)?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extract images from a target HTML page, this is the wrong place to do it.

When you write

```
page.on('response', this.extractImages);
```

puppeteer will call `this.extractImages` and pass to it an object of the [Response class](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-response), which contains various information on how the server responded to the request, most importantly, headers. (That is is exactly what you showed in the question). But it doesn't contain HTML.

---

To parse any data from a page you would rather wait for it to load completely and then use page.evaluate to extract any information necessary:

```
'use strict';

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const url = 'https://example.com';
const extractImages = (selector) => {
    const imgs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector));
    return imgs.map(img => img.src);
}
const selector = '#some .content img';

(async() => {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch()

    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'networkidle'});

    const images = await page.evaluate(extractImages, selector);

    console.log(images.join('\n'));
    browser.close();

})();
```

Adapted from [this example](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/examples/search.js), more examples can be found [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/tree/master/examples).

In puppeteer there are several more ways to interact with a target page but I personally find `page.evaluate` more logical since it clearly separates node script context from a target page's context, just like in PhantomJS.

Comment: This scenario won't do it as many times, images come in not in <img> tag. It could be in div or background, etc.

Comment: The example is unimportant, just wanted to help. The real answer is first two pararaphs. Ok, I'll rephrase.